# UIScrollView and UITextField scrolling and orientation problem

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I am facing problem in scrolling when keyboard appears on textfield click

I have tried using lots of source code but they not support all the orientation of iPad.

Also when view open in popoverview then it creates problem.

What could be done?
i want dynamic solution not static paches , thank you all in advance
Please Help and Suggest.

Comment: what problem are you facing in scrolling???

Answer (score 0):

[**Here**](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tag/uitextfield) is the dynamic solution to scroll UITextfield while keyboard is being displayed.

**Basic Code:**

```
    -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
    {
        [self scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:textField];
    }

    - (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView 
    {  
        [self scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:textView];  
    }  

    - (void)scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:(UIView *)theView 
    {  
        CGFloat viewCenterY = theView.center.y;  
        CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];    
        CGFloat availableHeight = applicationFrame.size.height - keyboardBounds.size.height;    // Remove area covered by keyboard    
        CGFloat y = viewCenterY - availableHeight / 2.0;  
        if (y < 0) {  
            y = 0;  
        }  
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(applicationFrame.size.width, applicationFrame.size.height + keyboardBounds.size.height);  
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, y) animated:YES];  
    }
```